# How to create multiple html tables from multiple csv files using a shell script

Tags: shell-script, html, sed, csv, awk

I have two csv files like this:

*test1.csv:*

```
user size
aaa   10
bbb   20
ccc   30
```

*test2.csv:*

```
name value
www   5
mmm   8
ppp   9
```

I want to convert this to two separate HTML tables using a shell script. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the fields in your files separated by spaces and you've only two fields in every row:

```
sed -E '1 s@^([^ ]*) *(.*)@<table><tr><th>\1</th><th>\2</th></tr>@ ; \
  2,$ s@^^([^ ]*) *(.*)@<tr><td>\1</td><td>\2</td></tr>@ ; \
  $ s,.*,&</table>,' test1.csv
```

The first line assumes the first line of `test1.csv` is table head. Open the `<table>` tag, a `<tr>` and enclose every field between `<th>`. After it closes the `</tr>`. The second line is similar but only transforms from the second line of `test1.csv`.

The third line appends the last line (`$`) the `</table>` to close the `table` tag (opened in first line).

You can do it with pure `awk` of course.